# jQuery Refresh/Reload Page if Ajax Success after predicted time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use Jquery to make an Ajax request. The server returns Json object with value "true or false" like this:

```
return Json(new { success = false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
```

Is there any way to refresh page after 5 seconds if the server returns true?

Answer (score 57):

In your ajax success callback do this:

```
success: function(data){
   if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)
      setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
           location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
      }, 5000); 
   }
}
```

As you want to reload the page after 5 seconds, then you need to have a timeout as suggested in the answer.

Comment: What does 5000 means..?

Comment: @BalaKarthik that's time in ms which is equal to 5 seconds.

Comment: 5000 means 5000 milliseconds ( 1 second = 1000 milliseconds)

Answer (score 17):

```
location.reload();
```

You can use the `reload` function in your `if` condition for success and the page will reload after the condition is successful.

Comment: Good idea to reload page but the main point here is setTimeout function :)

Answer (score 10):

```
if(success == true)
{
  //For wait 5 seconds
  setTimeout(function() 
  {
    location.reload();  //Refresh page
  }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this way 
Using `ajaxStop` + `setInterval`,, this will refresh the page after any **XHR[ajax]** request in the same page

```
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            location.reload();
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: It works with me but roload on loop
Is there any way to make it work only when a Ajax value is changed

Comment: @SaidErraoudy you can make `if statement` to check if  the value has changed

Comment: Something like that : https://jsfiddle.net/wLyoqrme/1/

Comment: @SaidErraoudy Create a global flag variance and set it's value whenever you get result from server. Then compare the current result with it

Answer (score 2):

```
var val = $.parseJSON(data);
if(val.success == true)
{
 setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 5000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax("youurl", function(data){
    if (data.success == true)
    setTimeout(function(){window.location = window.location}, 5000); 
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers here, just out of curiosity after looking into this today, is it not best to use `setInterval` rather than the `setTimeout`?

```
setInterval(function() {
location.reload();
}, 30000);
```

let me know you thoughts.

Comment: setTimeout function is called one time only, the setInterval will be called many times. You know which one is suitable and better in this case

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
    $.ajax({
        success: function (response) {
            location.reload();
            },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }
    });
```